# Why this XPath (all nodes to the target) can not see element in response (with SoapUI)?

Tags: xpath, groovy, soapui

Here is an xml responce I am trying to explore with [soapui](/questions/tagged/soapui) script (groovy) assertions:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <myInfoResponse xmlns="http://test.test.test.test">
         <pc>1234223234</pc>
         <item>
            <sl>val1</sl>
            <he>val2</he>
            <ko>val3</ko>
            <fo>val4</fo>
            <ok>val5</ok>
            <di>val6</di>
         </item>
...
```

Why I can not get `pc` node's value with:

```
def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/myInfoResponse/pc")
// Output: null
holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/myInfoResponse[1]/pc[1]")
// Output: null
```

And I can get value by XPath

```
holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]/*[1]")
// Output: 1234223234
holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[1]/*[2]/*[4]")
// Output: val4
```

Why?

Comment: http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html

Comment: Because of default namespace. If you want to fetch regardless of namespace with holder then `holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/*:myInfoResponse/*:pc")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it was mentioned in the comments, the element `myInfoResponse` has default namespace. That is why you were not able to get the value of `pc`.

Below is the Script Assertion using `getNodeValue`

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(context.response)
//You may also change the prefix other than mentioned in the response like below
holder.declareNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
//Below namespace uri does not have prefix in the response, but now setting prefix as ns
holder.declareNamespace('ns', 'http://test.test.test.test')
def pcValue = holder.getNodeValue('//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:myInfoResponse/ns:pc')
log.info "Response of has pc value : ${pcValue}"
```

*Using **XmlSlurper***:

```
assert context.response
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def pcValue = parsedXml.'**'.find {it.name() == 'pc'}.text()
log.info "Response of has pc value : ${pcValue}" 
//Similarly you can find any element name, for example item/fo
def foVal = parsedXml.'**'.find {it.name() == 'fo'}.text()
log.info "fo value is : ${foVal}"
```

Comment: Are you still looking for more information as none of them marked as answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Still do not know how to get `holder.getNodeValue()` working, but I have found `XmlSlurper` in [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) that is working fine.

[Groovy docs "Processing XML"](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)

```
def Envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
log.info("pc = " + Envelope.Body.myInfoResponse.pc.text())
// Output: 1234223234
```